# extract substring from a string using regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

try to extract for substrings that match pattern in string.
for example i have text like the one below

```
[ Pierre/NNP Vinken/NNP ]
,/, 
[ 61/CD years/NNS ]
old/JJ ,/, will/MD join/VB 
[ the/DT board/NN ]
as/IN 
[ a/DT nonexecutive/JJ director/NN Nov./NNP 29/CD ]
./. 
[ Mr./NNP Vinken/NNP ]
is/VBZ 
[ chairman/NN ]
of/IN
```

and i want to extract whatever before slash (/) and whatever after slash, but somehow my regex extracts the first substring and ignore the rest of substrings in the line.

my output is something like this below :

```
tag:Pierre/NNP Vinken - word:Pierre/NNP Vinken/NNP ->1
tag:, - word:,/, ->1
tag:61/CD years - word:61/CD years/NNS ->1
tag:old/JJ ,/, will/MD join - word:old/JJ ,/, will/MD join/VB ->1
tag:the/DT board - word:the/DT board/NN ->1
tag:as - word:as/IN ->1
tag:a/DT nonexecutive/JJ director/NN Nov./NNP 29 - word:a/DT nonexecutive/JJ director/NN Nov./NNP 29/CD ->1
tag:. - word:./. ->1
tag:Mr./NNP Vinken - word:Mr./NNP Vinken/NNP ->1
tag:is - word:is/VBZ ->1
tag:chairman - word:chairman/NN ->1
tag:of - word:of/IN ->1
```

but what i am actually want is something like this below

```
tag:NNP  - word:Pierre ->1
tag:NNP  - word:Vinken ->1
tag:,    - word:,      ->1
tag:CD   - word:61     ->1
.
.
etc.
```

code i used :

```
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        #remove square brackets
        $line=~s/[\[\]]//;

        while($line =~m/((\s*(.*))\/((.*)\s+))/gi)
        {
            $word=$1;
            $tag=$2;
            #remove whitespace from left and right of string
            $word=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
            $tag=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
            $tags{$tag}++;
            $tagHash{$tag}{$word}++;
        }

    }
foreach my $str (sort keys %tagHash)
{
    foreach my $s (keys %{$tagHash{$str}} )
    {
        print "tags:$str - word: $s-> $tagHash{$str}{$s}\n";
    }
}
```

any idea why my regex does not behave as should be

EDIT:

in text files that i am parsing has wild character and punctuation as well, which is mean that files will have something like this :
''/''
"/"
,/,
./.
?/?
!/!
.
.
.
etc

so i want to capture all of these things not only alphabetic and numeric characters.

Comment: that's because of the greedy nature of .*  why don't you do a split on /

Comment: the whole reason because when you hit something like this [./.] where whatever on the left side of the slash is word and whatever on the right side is tag for this word and in this case both will be the same and that could be confusing  if i store them to array, but i think you are right, because in this case odd positions in array will represent tags and even position will represent word.

Comment: try `\b([\w\.]+?)\/([\w\.]+)\b` @kero

Comment: or: `while( $line =~ m!([^/\s]+)/([^/\s]+)!g ) {`

Comment: @MohaMad you answer works perfect , but it fall off when there when you have a wild character like (," ' ' ).

Comment: Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/BMSyht/1): `\s*([\w\.,'"]+?)\/([\w\.,'"]+)\s*` @kero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer-most set of parentheses, around your whole pattern, gets captured into `$1`, what is clearly not intended. Also, the greediness of `.*\/` means that it takes everything up to the *last* `/`. Likewise, `.*\s+` leaves only the very last space.

One way to do this is by using the *negated character class*

```
my ($word, $tag) = m{ ([^/\s]+) / ([^/\s]+) }x;
```

The pattern `[^/\s]+` matches a string of one-or-more consecutive characters, each being any other than `/` or whitespace. So you get a "*word*" before and after `/`. If you take "*whatever after slash*" as the text says it is unclear what should be before the next slash.

Your approach can then go as

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    while ( $line =~ m{ ([^/\s]+) / ([^/\s]+) }gx )
    {
        $tagHash{$2}{$1}++;
    }
}
```

The other count seems unrelated so I left it out to focus on the question.

---

However, there is a big bit missing here.

This approach cannot detect when a line differs from the expected format. For example

```
word1/tag1 word2/tag2/ tag3/word4/tag4
```

produces wrong results, quietly. Some violations get skipped, but there are many bad cases.

One way to catch this is to pre-process the line, checking that there are at least two words between all slashes and at least one before first and after last. This means that each line is processed twice, and it also gets messier. For example

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    my @parts = split '/', $line;
    if (not shift @parts or not pop @parts or grep { 2 > split } @parts) {
        warn "Unexpected format: $line";
        next;
    }

    $tagHash{$2}{$1}++  while $line =~ m{ ([^/\s]+) / ([^/\s]+) }gx;
}
```

This check changes the `@parts` array, so if that array is needed later then better use

```
if (!$parts[0] or !$parts[-1] or grep { 2 > split } @parts[1..@parts-2])  { ...
```

where instead of `grep` one can also use the short-circuiting `any` from [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#any)

Another way would be to change the approach, and parse the line carefully instead of blindly hopping over regex matches.  Since the first and last may have only one word this may be hard to do with a regex. It is probably clearer and more practical to just split and work with the array.

It is hard to imagine a format *always* matching data so I'd suggest to consider some of this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have `tag/word`s that `tag` and `word` may be everything, except some characters like `],[,\s,`:

```
\s*([^\[\]\s]+?)\/([^\[\]\s]+)\s*
    ^^^^^^^^^1
```

This regex is similar to your original pattern. (See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/BMSyht/2))

Description:

1- This Capturing Group match every character `.` that is not `[`,`]` or `\s`